# NextJS + ExpressJS Error with On Demand Entries Ping

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, next.js

I'm using NextJS and custom server with Express, But I got a problem when defining my routes in Express.

When I define Express routes like below it will throw an errors

```
app.get('/:username', handle.profile)
app.get('/:username/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.send('id')
})
```

But the errors just appears when I'm in Development mode. Which is when I go with Production the errors not shown.

Though errors in console, but all run normally, I just can't figure out why the error message coming. It's a weird.

Here's the errors message

> Error with on-demand-entries-ping: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0

Here's screenshot of the errors
[image: Express routes error]

But when I define Express routes like below

```
app.get('/:username', handle.profile)
app.get('/:username/forum/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.send('id')
})
```

In Production or Development mode the errors is go on, my application going well.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Next.JS bugs and already fixed by https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/1658

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older issue, but if you're still experiencing this error double-check your npm scripts in package.json.  Since you're using a custom server, the standard `"dev": "next"` script won't work.  You'll need something along the lines of `"dev": "node server.js"` to run the app via your Express instance.

Comment: Hi, it's NextJS bugs
It's already patched by NextJS Developer (Arunoda) :)